# WAC Access Token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Some requests on excel workbooks that were working last evening have stopped today with WAC Access token errors. I was able to fire these requests on the same documents, same account, from the graph explorer last night but have now stopped working. I've tried on a new excel document - seems to be the same issue on all requests.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/b!NBYfXMQB_UiQc8A8qffNGNLOxiFMLG9EsCddg7MOh-ZAG5qxOvxWSoxPmlHEsuab/items/01NVUYB5LJSC6B5B5PKJDJZT3PFBNFEWC3/workbook

{
    "error": {
        "code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "Could not obtain a WAC access token.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "463d6282-0b25-416a-b635-a4a6964c86f4",
            "date": "2016-04-06T15:57:43"
        }
    }
}

Any ideas? Service Health issues perhaps? I was getting unknown / null objects earlier today and just started working. Or has there been an API change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue should be fixed now. Can you try again?

Comment: no it's still not work on my particular tenant. I'm a MS FTE Hardik, this is working on the MS tenant, but not on my trial O365 tenant (which it was last night). You can ping me on skype bagervin@microsoft.com if you want me to try something.

Comment: Hi Barry, We rolled out this fix this morning to all tenants. It should be working by now.

Comment: @SkyLiu-Microsoft I am getting the same error while accessing .csv file but for .xlsx it works fine. Can you please help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014639/403-forbidden-on-reading-csv-file-in-onedrive

Answer (score 1):

We at Zapier are getting this as well. We're in contact with the Excel team and if we get news we will report back!